# How to use a class from a parent directory in Java?

Tags: java

For example, I have a class called `Foo` inside `Foo.java` which will use a class called `Bar` inside `../Bar.java`. Is there any way to make that work when I do `javac Foo.java`?

Answer (score 3):

Add your class to classpath..

```
javac -cp "path to your Bar.class" Foo.java
```

You will need to import that class in your `Foo.java` also.. Better use a package, and give the classpath till the directory containing your package..That way you will be able to give different namespaces to your classes..

So, if your package is: - `pkg1.pkg2.Bar`and you have saved your `.java` to a directory named `Demo`, then your classpath should contain path till `Demo`.. And your classes will actually be under two more directory `pkg1/pkg2/Bar.class` inside `Demo` directory..

```
Demo+
    |
    +-- B.java (`Under package pkg1.pkg2)
    |
    +--pkg1+
    |      |
    |      +--pkg2+
    |             |
    |             +-- B.class
    |
    +-- A.java (`Under no package`) - Add - import pkg1.pkg2.B 
    |
    +-- A.class (javac -cp . A.java) - Will search the package pkg1.pkg2 in current directory
```

Even though `.` is not needed there, you can replace it with any path, if your `B.class` is somewhere else..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are both your classes and belong to the same module, you should be using packages and both classes should exist in the same package hierarchy. Then it would work automatically.

Packages would be something like com.company.application.module.Bar and com.company.application.module.subcomponent.Foo, for example. See more discussion on correct package naming:

- [Oracle.com: naming packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)
- [wikipedia: package naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions)

You can also do `javac -sourcepath path/to/src/solution/java;path/to/src/test/java` to point to several locations explicitly (note that `-classpath` will also work, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441760/differences-between-classpath-and-sourcepath-options-of-javac) about the differences).

If we're talking about separate components that don't exist in the same module, you'd just use classpath to make the code aware of both (or preferrably some dependency mechanism like Maven that works out the stuff under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

Your classes have packages, which are mirrored in the directory structure. E.g. `com/company/pk/Foo` and `com/company/Bar` - then you can reference them using the `import` statement. If your classes are in different directories but don't declare a `package`, then you are doing it wrong.

[Read about packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)