# how to import java class from parent directory

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a class from a parent directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703092/how-to-use-a-class-from-a-parent-directory-in-java)

i have a public class which is in current directory, i need to extend a class which is in parent directory, how can i plot it in java

`public class A extends B
{`

`}`
Here B is in Parent directory ,, Any answer for this

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Comment: @Brian its all the subsclass package is in same directory,, But in my questions i mentioned the package which is in parent directory..

Answer (score 1):

```
import parent.B;
```

Where `parent` is the parent package.

Comment: You are right , when the  package is in current directory, But my package is in previous directory i mean parent directory..

Comment: @KarmegaShiva I don't follow. If `B` is in package `pkg`, then `import pkg.B` will do.

Comment: @KarmegaShiva If you are still having difficulty, please try to explain it to me. If the above answer fixed it, please accept the answer.

Comment: @KarmegaShiva You seem to be a little confused between package and directory, a package is (virtually) synonymous with a directory. `package misc` can only exist in a directory called `misc`, it would be a compile-time error for `package misc.other` to be in the directory `misc`.