# -sourcepath vs -classpath

Tags: java, classpath, javac

Studying for the oracle certification I am trying all the possible scenarios that might occur during the exam.
For example, here there is a little doubt about shell command line (unix based):

Let's imagine there is a folder called `myProject` and a sub folder called `myProject/source.`

File `SubFile.java` is in the folder `myProject/source` and another file `File.java` is in `myProject` folder.

By typing the following commands I get to different behaviors:

`cd source` (therefore, currently I am on "myProject/source")

`javac -sourcepath ../ File.java`
 // The command ../ does not work to access "Folder"
then after compiling `File.java` from `myProject` folder and returning to the sub Folder if I try:

`javac -classpath ../ SubFile.java`

// with the flag `-classpath` it seems to accept the `../` syntax to access the `super` folder.

Do you know why it works like this? and moreover is there any chance to access the `super` folder  with the `-sourcepath` flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether `SubFile` also references `File`.

Consider the following code:

```
public class SubFile {
    private static File file = new File();
}
```

Assumed that this file is located in your source folder, and assumed that you are in the source folder, then

```
javac -sourcepath ../ SubFile.java
```

will compile `SubFile.java` into `SubFile.class` inside the source folder, and will compile `File.java` into `File.class` in the parent folder. If there is no dependency between those files, then the compiler will *not* compile `File.java` (means, the compiler will not automatically compile all files on the `sourcepath`).

When compiling with `-classpath`, then the classpath is also searched for source files, *unless*  you explicitly specify a separate sourcepath - in the following case, the compiler will throw an error (assumed that you have cleaned the File.class file before):

```
javac -classpath .. -sourcepath \temp SubFile.java
```

See also [javac - Java programming language compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and [Differences between classpath and sourcepath options of javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441760/differences-between-classpath-and-sourcepath-options-of-javac) for more information.

The important point from these two links is:

> Note: Classes found through the class path may be subject to automatic recompilation if their sources are also found.