# Compiling Java files with the dependent jars using windows Cmd

Tags: java, cmd, jar, importerror

I have 5 .java files in src folder and many dependent jars in lib folder
While Compiling the .java files with the jars i am facing error as,

**src\Grapher.java:12: error: package org.jfree.chart does not exist
import org.jfree.chart.*;**

My directory sturcture is,
C:\Grapher\src*.java
C:\Grapher\lib*.jar

I am using the commond **javac -cp .;lib/*.jar src/*.java**

Comment: Looks actually good. Have you tried listing the jar files by name; instead of using "*"?

Comment: No !! because there are many dependent different jars for different java files

Comment: Then just go for a simple experiment and add the freechar jar with its full name and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I don't know if your use of wildcard will work. Is that windows? What exactly? In POSIX shells, I expect your `.;lib/*.jar` to fail (because of the way wildcards expand) but I am not sure of your environment...

Comment: @MariusSiuram In windows, expansion is done by the application, isnt it. Windows wouldnt know how to expand / - and javac finds it way to the files in src

Comment: Please be aware that this is a very low level approach. Going for build tools like Maven or Gradle is the contemporary way.

Comment: @JFMeier There is still some merit in understand *how* things work on the most basic lowest level. I think it is actually good practice to start on that level, and only turn to tools such maven or gradle after figuring *what* those tools do for you.

Comment: @GhostCat I just wanted to point out that this is not the way you should work for productive code.

Comment: Sure thing ... it is not like a flagged your comment for "not constructive" or so ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have JFreeChart jar in your lib folder
2. You have to wrap arguments of `-cp` to brackets
3. You didn't provide sourcepath.

Try this:

```
javac -classpath "lib/*" -sourcepath src src/*.java
```

Note: this will work only if your java files are located exactly in `src` folder. In case if you have package declaration in your classes you have to specify package structure.

eg: `src/com/company/*.java`

Comment: To my knowledge usage of -sourcepath is optional. And when telling to compile all files in src, (and no sub packages are used) - what is the point of using it?

Comment: According to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html the sourcepath could be skipped in case if classpath includes folder with sources. But it is not the case here.

Comment: @GhostCat you're right, tried locally - it works. Could you hint me the link on documentation which explains why it can be skipped.

Comment: I just found a statement "is optional" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441760/differences-between-classpath-and-sourcepath-options-of-javac

Comment: @OleksandrShpota Thanks!! javac -classpath "lib/*" -sourcepath src src/*.java worked perfectly.

Comment: @Oleksandr Shpota what if i want to create a war file from the above file that i have ?

Comment: Try to follow one of tutorials, for instance http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-war-file-using-the-jar-command.html