# Java command to run the main class

Tags: java, command, javac

I have been away from Java stuff for quite sometime, need some help about basic stuff.

I have the following project structure :

[image]

There are no manifest files etc, its just a raw folder structure.

I wanted to know command to compile these java classes from root folder `Data Structures - Java` and command to execute compiled classes.

I did try

```
javac -d build com.codesuman.datastructures.Main
```

This worked first time but failed in next attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but failed` How? What's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how that could work, even a single time :

```
javac -d build com.codesuman.datastructures.Main
```

In `javac`, the last argument is "source files". It has to specify location of java source to compile in terms of **filesystem location** : that is file or directory.
 But that `com.codesuman.datastructures` refers to a java package. Something like that is expected : `com/codesuman/datastructures/Main.java`.

So, to compile that class in the `build` directory, do that :

```
javac -d build com/codesuman/datastructures/Main.java
```

But if `Main.java` relies on other classes, which looks possible according to your snapshot, you also need to compile these classes.
So a more idiomatic approach in this case is :

```
javac -d build com/codesuman/datastructures/*.java
```

But beware the subfolders are not compiled.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense now & it worked when i execute `javac` command from src folder. To add what should i do if i want to build from outside src folder say i want to be in root folder and execute `javac` command ?

Comment: You can specify the classpath with `-cp src` for example.

Comment: My understanding was to use -cp for `java` command. My question was how to use `javac` command directly from outside `src` folder. Thanks.

Comment: but `cp` is for both `javac` and `java`. You have the compile time classpath and the runtime classpath. So for your question, use `cp` too.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx, will go through documentation.

Comment: You are welcome. And you also have  `-sourcepath`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441760/differences-between-classpath-and-sourcepath-options-of-javac

Answer (score 1):

Main class seems to be inside linear folder
This should do the job `javac -d build com.codesuman.datastructures.linear.Main`